# How to make a random delete script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new on coding. I made a runner platform but with some mistakes. Btw I am using this code to random crate Obstacles. Here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public GameObject[] myObjects;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, myObjects.Length);
        Vector3 randomSpawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7, 7), 1, Random.Range(player.position.z + 45, 99000));

        Instantiate(myObjects[randomIndex], randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Now I am trying  to make a script which is deletes Obstacles behind my player. Because after 2 or 3 minutes game starts lagging.

I am working on it for 1 hour, I tried to change RandomSpawn Script but that didn't work.
I wrote a code like this... Not worked :(

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomDelete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void DestroyGameObject()
    {
        Destroy(Random.Range(-7, 7), 1, Random.Range(40, player.position.z - 15));

    }

    public void Destroy(int v1, int v2, float v3)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That is the code which is not working. I need a script which is deletes obstacles behind player.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array to hold the game objects with the line:

```
public GameObject[] myObjects;
```

But you don't seem to be storing a reference in there when you create your crate obstacles.

You need to put something like this:

```
        var spawnedCrate = Instantiate(myObjects[randomIndex], randomSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        myObjects[CrateNum]=spawnedCrate  CrateNum++ ;
```

Then you can keep track of all your crates Game objects and select one randomly to destroy.

Note you need to initialise your array (new()) , and keep track of which "cratenumber" you are up to in the array using an int "CrateNum" which you also need to declare.